# Custom ribbonx XML onAction makes it not load

Tags: excel, ribbonx

I have an xlam file that I want to add a custom ribbonX buttons to.

I use Custom UI Editor and with this xml it "works".

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Tab1" label="LeaveReport">
                <group id="Group1" label="Formatering">
                    <button id="Button1" imageMso="ChartSwitchRowColumn" size="large"/ >
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

But if I add onaction to make the button do something it does not load at all. Meaning the tab and buttons are not there at all.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Tab1" label="LeaveReport">
                <group id="Group1" label="Formatering">
                    <button id="Button1" imageMso="ChartSwitchRowColumn" size="large"/ onAction="formatera_for_pivot_tabell()"/ >
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I have also tried without `()`.
What am I doing wrong here? A button without an action is quite useless :-/

Comment: I found the problem by "luck". There is a xlam called RibbonEditor.xlam that can create the xml code too. And it also have a "vba creator". And that is where I noticed the sub should be called as following: `Public Sub formatera_for_pivot_tabell(control As IRibbonControl)` and not as you usually do: `Sub formatera_for_pivot_tabell()`. I will make an answer of it when I have time. Just posting this so that nobody wastes time on it.

Answer (score 1):

To get your custom ribbon UI working correctly you must:

1. Specify the ribbon callback in the ribbon XML without brackets.

   ```
   onAction="formatera_for_pivot_tabell"
   ```
2. The XML namespace should be updated and look like the following one:

   `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"`
3. Define the callback in the code-behind file.

   - C#: `void OnAction(IRibbonControl control)`
   - VBA: `Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)`
   - C++: `HRESULT OnAction([in] IRibbonControl *pControl)`
   - Visual Basic: `Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)`

It should have a signature specified in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v%3Doffice.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v%3Doffice.12)#button)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))